# Issue with jackson-datatype-jsr310 in Quarkus

Tags: java, json, quarkus

I have a service that calls external API and converts what it gets into some Object.
I tested that service and it works fine, it converts it correctly into wanted Object. The issue is that it fails when it comes to the controller and has to return the result. It fails on ZonedDateTime even though it did it successfully (I checked it in debugger).
This is the error:

***Java 8 date/time type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain***

I added dependency that is needed:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

I did include that module in my Object Mapper:

```java
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public Class() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    }
```

This code is migrated from Spring Boot, I am not sure if there is other way to do this because the documentation is not there and community is not that large yet so I can't find any ideas online.

Comment: Where is the Jackson being used in your code? Can you provide a snippet? Also, can you provide the entire stacktrace?

Comment: To configure the `ObjectMapper` used by Quarkus for REST marshalling and unmarshalling, create a bean of type `ObjectMapperCustomizer`: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.quarkus/quarkus-jackson/latest/io/quarkus/jackson/ObjectMapperCustomizer.html. Its `customize` method lets you update the actually used instance.

Comment: @RobSpoor I have tried that and it doesn't work, I inspected Object Mapper and it has that module registered but it just doesn't work and it fails somewhere in line like this:
        return Response.ok(service.method(parameter)).build();
It basically fails after the service returns result successfully and it has to return the object to user, so object mapping is basically done in service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using RestEASY Classic instead of **RestEASY Reactive Jackson**. When I changed the dependency it worked.